# Os Itens do Menu Dropdown não mudam de cor

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

UPDATE

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e coloquei o menu do bootstrap e gostaria de que os itens do menu mudassem de cor e não ficasse nessa cor preta e sim na cor `#00008B`

Itens do menu

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li class="conteudo_drop"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Meus Pedidos</a></li>
                       <li class="conteudo_drop"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Meus Dados</a></li>
                       <li class="conteudo_drop"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Fale Conosco</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><button type="button" onclick="" class="btn_entrar" >Entrar</button> </a></li>
                         <li class="conteudo_drop"><a href="cadastro.jsp"> Cliente novo? Cadastre-se</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

CSS

```
 .dropdown-menu{

        background-color: white;
        color:white;
    }
    .conteudo_drop{

        color:#00008B !important;
    }
```

Comment: Eu penso que você não pode pôr um `<li>` dentro de uma `<div>`

Comment: Adicione a class que tem nas divs nos `<li>` e depois tire as divs

Comment: eu tirei a div dentro do li e coloquei a class dentro da li, os itens apareceram mas o efeito hover não funcionou

Comment: l_like_trains eu atualizei a pergunta e coloquei o novo codifo

Comment: Já tentou usar `color: red !important?`

Comment: O que voce quer que mude de cor? o fundo ou as letras? talvez um exemplo verificavel seja util pra te ajudarmos

Comment: quero que mude a cor de fundo e a cor dos itens.Exemplo  .conteudo_drop a:hover{
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
background-color: blue;
    }

Comment: Rafael Augusto funcionou agora ao passar o mouse por cima dos itens eles mudam de cor e a cor de fundo, mas agora o problema é que não consigo mudar a cor do itens do menu, atualizei a pergunta e o novo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag `<a>` tem um estilo default, e no Bootstrap com certeza a cor está aplicada diretamente nela.

Então você deve aplicar a cor na tag `<a>`, assim:

```
.conteudo_drop a {
  color:#00008B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de colocar uma classe na tag li, coloque um style dentro dele para determinar a cor que deseja.

Se não funcionar, pode entrar no código do Bootstrap e mudar a cor diretamente na classe .conteudo_drop.